# Check if palindrome while ignoring special characters

Tags: recursion, python-3.x

I'm failing the last test case, which is the one with the spaces and single quotation mark.
I used s.strip, but the error still persists.

Is there another way to go about this?

Thank you.

```
from test import testEqual
def removeWhite(s):
    s.strip()
    s.strip("'")
    return s

def isPal(s):

    if s == "" or len(s) == 1:
        return True
    if removeWhite(s[0]) != removeWhite(s[-1]):
        return False
    return isPal(removeWhite(s[1:-1]))

testEqual(isPal(removeWhite("x")),True)
testEqual(isPal(removeWhite("radar")),True)
testEqual(isPal(removeWhite("hello")),False)
testEqual(isPal(removeWhite("")),True)
testEqual(isPal(removeWhite("hannah")),True)
testEqual(isPal(removeWhite("madam i'm adam")),True)
```

Answer (score 0):

At first your `removeWhite` function doesn't return all spaces because strip only removes from the end and the beginning of a string. See:

```
>>> "   a   ".strip()
'a'
>>> "   a a   ".strip()
'a a'
```

So i suggest this approach:

```
def removeWhite(s):
    return ''.join(filter(lambda x: x not in " '", s))
```

Please note that I use join because filter returns an iterator which needs to be converted back to a string.

For finding the palindromes i would suggest this function:

```
def isPal(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:                       # Special case to prevent KeyError later
        return True
    stripped = removeWhite(s)             # Strip off all whitespaces
    first = stripped[:len(stripped) // 2] # First half of the string
    if len(stripped) % 2:                 # Length of string is even?
        second = stripped[len(stripped) // 2 + 1:] # Drop the middle character
    else:
        second = stripped[len(stripped) // 2:] # Else keep it
    secondrev = ''.join(reversed(second)) # Reverse the second half
    return first == secondrev             # And return wether they're equal.
```

This holds for all your examples. But it think your `isPal` function should work too if you fix your `removeWhite` function